# With Dexie should bulkPut assign the identity Primary Key values to the object being saved the same way put() does?

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

I'm using Dexie to work with IndexedDB.  I'm using:

```
db.version(1).stores({
    activities: '++LocalActivityId'
});
```

to have the PK LocalActivityId automatically incremented/assigned.

When I use **put**:

```
db.activities.put(activity).then(function(newId){
    // don't even need to use "newId", the value is already assigned to my object
    console.log("This will have the new LocalActivityId " + activity.LocalActivityId );
});
```

it assigns LocalActivityId to my object with the new value from the database, but when I try bulkPut, it doesn't do this:

```
db.activities.bulkPut(activities).then(function (lastKey) {
  console.log("There is nothing here: " + activities[0].LocalActivityId);
});
```

bulkPut also only returns the last new ID, so there is no easy way for me to get the IDs of all the objects that were just inserted.

Is this the expected behavior?

If this is expected, what do people do if they are trying to do a bulk insert of objects and need to know the new IDs assigned to those objects?

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of the primary key to given object in put() and add() was never documented, and are subject for change. I understand that one would expect bulkPut() to behave the same way, but it would be of a significant performance cost as the bulk-methods does not listen to the success events of each individual operation but only the last one. The ID's could be computed though if all your objects lack primary keys while being added and the table's primary key is auto-incremented. If you put in a mix where some have their primary key set and some not, you would have to split the put operation into two array - one bulkPut() of items that has the primary key in their objects, and another (that could equally well be a bulkAdd()) that adds the items that lacks a primary key. The ID's can be computed by substracting 1 from the last insterted ID for each one preceeding it.